# How to compile and run multi-module jersey web service?

Tags: maven, jersey, multi-module

I'm new to maven and I'm trying to create a new multi-module jersey web service following [this tutorial](http://subodh1287.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/hello-world/).
So now my project is composed of 3 maven modules:

```
* Model module
* Core module
* web service module
```

now, since I'm new to maven projects I don't know how to compile these modules and run my web service. What commands should I use when I update one of those 3 modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one would run `mvn clean install` in the parent project and then `mvn jetty:run` from the web-service module (assuming you're using the Jetty plugin).

Comment: should I repeat this every time I make some changes to one of the modules(core/model), or it would be updated automatically?

Comment: If you're compiling from the shell, then yes. If you're using Eclipse with m2eclipse there's an option to enable "Workspace Resolution", in which case Eclipse will take care of compiling the dependencies for you.